# T4 Get Value of Enum Members

Tags: c#, t4

I'm trying to generate a typescript interfaces class complete with proper enums.

I'm stuck on how to get the value of the enum member.

Enum.Members gets CodeElements, not CodeProperties and if I try and cast, it breaks. It also breaks with CodeEnum.

What I'm trying to do is get the value so that it's explicit with value1 = 1, value2= 2 etc. instead of just value1, value2 because the enums may not be 0 based.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `CodeEnum`?  What API?  (I don't see it in [`System.CodeDom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: I'm using taligent t4 so it may be specific but in any event, it doesn't work. Trying to get the definition, which appears that it might work if I could cast to codeproperty but I can't or don't know how..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"`CodeElements`" sounds as if you are using the EnvDTE interfaces to gain access to your enumerations. If so, all enum items are in the `Members`-Property of the `EnvDTE.CodeEnum` type. They are of type `EnvDTE.CodeVariable` and the explicit value is stored in the `InitExpression` of the Variable.

Have a look at this Enum:

```
    // C# Enum to reflect 
    public enum MyEnum { Hi = 10, There = 15 }
```

And this T4 CodeSnippet reflecting the Enum:

```
    <#
      // the enumeration object you already seem to have
      EnvDTE.CodeEnum theEnum;

      // iterate all enumeration items
      foreach(EnvDTE.CodeVariable variable in theEnum.Members)
      {
          // render name and value
          #><#= variable.Prototype #> = <#= variable.InitExpression.ToString() #>
    <#}
    #>
```

Should result in:

```
    Hi = 10
    There = 15
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't work when an enum member is assigned from another expression, e.g. `enum Foo { Bar = 1, Baz = Bar + 1 }` will say `Baz: Bar + 1`.